# JQuery slide down menu question

Tags: jquery, menu, slidedown

I have a simple horizontal menu that uses JQuery to vertically slide down a div with an unordered list when the parent href is clicked. It works fine when I only have two tabs across, but doesn't when I have more than 2. When there's more than 2, something happens with the SlideToggle and it ends up toggling several times instead of just once. I am relatively new to JQuery and this has got me stumped. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.menu_button').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var $this = $(this);
          var ulId = $this.attr("href");
          $this.parent().find("ul").not(ulId).slideUp("medium", function() {
            $ul = $this.parent().find("ul" + ulId )
            $ul.slideToggle('medium');


          });
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

And here is the HTML.  I didn't include the css, because I didn't think any of it was relevant, but I can post it if helps.

```
<div id="menus"> 
          <a href="#menu1" class="menu_button" id="home"></a>
          <a href="#menu2" class="menu_button" id="aboutus"></a>
          <a href="#menu3" class="menu_button" id="admissions"></a>

          <ul class="the_menu" id="menu1">
            <li><a href="#">A Website #3</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Website #4</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Link #1</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Link #2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Website #3</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Website #4</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Link #3</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Link #4</a></li> 

          </ul> 
          <ul class="the_menu" id="menu2">
            <li><a href="#">A Website #1</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Website #2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Link #1</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Link #2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Website #3</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Website #4</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Link #3</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Link #4</a></li> 

          </ul> 

          <ul class="the_menu" id="menu3">
            <li><a href="#">A Website #1</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Website #2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Link #1</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Link #2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Website #3</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Website #4</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Link #3</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">A Link #4</a></li> 

          </ul> 

          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

It works fine if you take out the third ul and anchor tag, but as soon as the third was is added in, it Toggles one too many times.

Here is the CSS

```
ul, li {
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
list-style:none;
}

div#menus {
position: relative;
background-color: #302f2f;

}

a.menu_button {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -4px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.menu_button img {
border:1px solid #1c1c1c;
  display: block;
}

.the_menu {
display:none;
width:1000px;

}

.the_menu li {

}

.the_menu li a {
color:#FFFFFF; 
text-decoration:none; 
padding:10px; 
display:block;
float:left;
}

.the_menu li a:hover {
padding:10px;
font-weight:bold;
color: #F00880;
}


.clear { 
clear: both;
}

#home {
background: url(button_sprite.png);
background-position: 0px 0px;
width:125px;
height:30px;
float:left;
}

#aboutus {
background: url(button_sprite.png);
background-position: -126px 0px;
width:125px;
height:30px;
float:left;
}

#admissions {
background: url(button_sprite.png);
background-position: -252px 0px;
 width:125px;
height:30px;
float:left;
}
```

EDIT: When a different href is clicked while one is down, I want the active one to slide up first, then the new one to slide down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this part of your code is where the problem lies -

```
$this.parent().find("ul").not(ulId).slideUp("medium", function() {
            $ul = $this.parent().find("ul" + ulId )
            $ul.slideToggle('medium');


          });
```

The anonymous function is getting called n times where n is the number of ul elements on your page minus one. So when you have 2 ul elements the function gets called once and everything works, but when you have 3 ul elements the function is getting called twice and you're seeing the strange behaviour. Try changing your code to this -

**EDIT** (changed original code after working through example on jsbin)

```
$(function(){
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.menu_button').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this);
      var ulId = $this.attr("href");
      var clicked_menu_is_visible = $this.parent().find("ul" + ulId).filter(':visible').length > 0;
      var visible_uls = $this.parent().find("ul").filter(':visible');
      if (visible_uls.length === 0) { //no menus showing - just show clicked menu 
        $ul = $this.parent().find("ul" + ulId);
        $ul.slideToggle('medium');
      }
      else { //close open menus (should only be one open) then open clicked menu
             //via callback 
        $this.parent().find("ul").filter(':visible').slideUp("medium", function() {
          $ul = $this.parent().find("ul" + ulId);
          //open clicked menu - unless menu was already open when clicked
          if (!clicked_menu_is_visible) $ul.slideToggle('medium');   
        });
      }  
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This fixed the problem of it getting called n times and so it only Toggles once. However, before, if a different href was clicked while one was already down, it would slide the down one up, and then slide down the one that was clicked. Now it just slides the new one on top of the one that was already down.

Comment: Hmm, that's not good. Would it be possible for you to post the css?

Comment: I edited the original and posted it a few minutes ago. It shows up for me, let me know if it isn't showing up for you. The menu won't look pretty without the image, but it should give you the basic function of it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you'd already posted the css. I've set up your code in a jsbin at jsbin.com/ukowug/5, the menu effect I'm getting is strange - could you have a look and see if it looks similar to what you are seeing?

Comment: If you fill up the menu with 8 href tags, like I did here http://jsbin.com/exukuj, the list items won't go up to the top like they are doing. I think its because I have the list items set to float:left. I'm pretty sure that's the strange behavior you are referring to. But yes, that is the same as I see.

Comment: I've changed the answer again, I think it's working on jsbin now - http://jsbin.com/atumef/2

Comment: The only issue now is that when you click on an open one to close, it slides up and then back down again. Sorry, I'm really not trying to be very picky, I do appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

A little context might help here, there seems to be a lot of unnecessary traversing going on in your jQueries. What you've described can be accomplished with:

```
$('a.menu_button').click(function(){
    $( $(this).attr("href") ).slideDown();   
});
```

But that doesn't make for a very pretty menu. First, because it relies on the UL's native position instead of that of the clicked A. Second, because there is no provision for "removing" the . Maybe a rollover menu is more appropriate?